# guardar en la base de datos con ajax?

Tags: c#, ajax, json, mvc

Hola desarrolladores estoy intentando guardar datos en mi base de datos usando ajax, pero al momento de ejecutar mi app parece omitir la porcion de codigo que me permitiria guardar los datos este es el codigo que estoy usando.

```
<script>
$(".clMotivo").click(function (event) {
            var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
            var data = $(this).serialize();
            var gafete = $("txtGafete").val();
            var datos = {};
            datos = {
                motivo_Id: id,
                gafete: gafete
            };
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:49851/api/visita/agregar",
                method: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(datos),
                contentType: "aplication/json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                    ocultarPopUpAcceso();
                }
            });            
        });
</script>
```

sera que me le falta algo en este mismo codigo o sera que debo serializar el json en el controller no llevo mucho programando en mvc y por eso tengo esa duda espero pueden entender mi punto y ayudarme un poco

Comment: El problema puede estar en el metodo. te fijaste si recibe algun valor?

Comment: puse unos breakpoint para ver si me devuelve los datos que necesito pero al momento de ejecutar no dentra la depuracion en el breakpoint

Comment: En `contentType` de tu Ajax te falta una **p** en *application*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenia un error en txtGafete que evitaba entrar al ajax a continuacion muestro el codigo que me ya corregido y funcional gracias a todos por sus aportes.

```
<script>
$(".clMotivo").click(function (event) {
            var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
            var gafete = $("#txtGafete").val();
            var datos = {};
            datos = {
                motivo_Id: $(this).attr("data-id")id,
                gafete: $("#txtGafete").val()
            };
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:49851/api/visita/agregar",
                method: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(datos),
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                    ocultarPopUpAcceso();
                }
            });            
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente es por tu url, es mejor trabajar con url relativas que ponerla completamente; en MVC normalmente se coloca controlador/funcion.
También puedes resumir un poco tus datos.

```
<script>
 $(".clMotivo").click(function (event) {
                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    contentType: "json",
                    url: "/visita/agregar",
                    data: {
                            motivo_Id: $(this).attr("data-id"),
                            gafete: $("txtGafete").val()
                   },
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                        ocultarPopUpAcceso();
                    }
                });            
            });
    </script>
```

Depura tu dando un breakpoint en tu controlador y asegúrate que estén entrando a la función agregar.

Answer (score 0):

Deberías colocar el código de la acción en el controlador que va procesar la información, solo con el JS que estás utilizando no es suficiente. Tu URL http://localhost:49851/api/visita/agregar hace referencia a una acción en un Controller Por ejemplo:

```
public class HomeController: Controller{

   private IDataService servicio;

   public HomeController(IDataService service){
        servicio = service;
   }

   Route["/visita/agregar"]
   public string Post(int motivo_Id, string gafete){
     servicio.guardar(motivo_Id, gafete)
     //retornar mensaje de respuesta al llamado ajax
   }

}
```

Idealmente tu controller no debería incluir la lógica de guardar en base de datos, eso violaría el Single Responsibility Principle por lo que deberías delegarlo a otra clase. Para guardar en base de datos tienes varias opciones. entre ellas esta ADO .NET aunque te recomiendo que le eches un ojo a Dapper.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ado-net-code-examples

https://stackexchange.github.io/Dapper/

Espero te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Para que la respuesta sea aceptada agrega un ejemplo de lo que estas explicando lo puedes hacer dando click en el link editar

Comment: Ah este punto es el que queria llegar es que no tengo ese codigo en mi controller como crees que lo debo estructurar

Comment: Gracias amigo por tu aporte encontre mi error en mi codigo omiti algo en mi ruta url que no me permitia guardar los datos.